# Скошенный угол у изображения

Tags: css

Имеется изображение, любое, желательно background,необходимо средствами css скосить угол как будто это реализовано через фотошоп:
вот пример - для слайдера :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

фокус  в том что это изображение смещается , т.е типичное поведение left  но покажется полностью как на скрине.
Нарезать фоты на фотошопе я умею , но не вариант.
Пробывал через border-top-width но происходит просто дублирование изображения , а нужен просто скос , сложность в том что фон не однородный, как это можно реализовать? Функциональность слайдера не интересует а только скос и изображения . для примера [обезьянка](http://xiper.net/examples/html-and-css-tricks/overclock-site/css-triangles/photo-star.html) но только один угол , левый правый - без разницы какой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
решено самостоятельно

Comment: решено самостоятельно

Comment: Изображение накрывается [фигурами ксс](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/) фон фигуры делает прозрачным или сплошным по необходимости

Comment: согласен - но если делать в автоматическом режиме - это будет бред

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:180px;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:30px auto;
}
.wrapper div{
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: transparent;
  top:0;
  transition:.8s;
}

.block_1{
  left:0%;
}
.block_2{
 left:-30%;
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  height:180px;
  position:absolute;
  transform-origin:top right;
  transform:skew(-10deg);
}
/*
.wrapper:hover div{
  left:0;
}
.left{
  left:;
}
.left1{

}
*/

.left{
  left:-230px;
}
.right{
  left:40px;
}
.stable{
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="block_1"><img src="http://images.forwallpaper.com/files/thumbs/preview/96/969580__green-dress_p.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="block_2"><img src="http://programfiles.narod.ru/wallpapers/big/676.jpeg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>



      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".block_1").hover(function(){
             $(this).toggleClass("right");
             $(".block_2").toggleClass("left");
               });
          });

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".block_2").hover(function(){
             $(this).toggleClass("stable");
          });
         });

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

вот этого я добивался ! и без всяких там ...

Comment: Это правильно-неправильно..... неправильно потому, что можете уменьшить `transform: skew` с  -10 до хотя бы -25 и поймете кривоту действий

Comment: ну так то да , но я не буду уменьшать -10 до -25 , он имено в таком виде должен быть , только теперь автоматизирую это

Comment: И некоторые фото у вас будут в неестественной позе скрюченные. Я бы не назвал это хорошим решением. Скорее костылем ради решения.

Comment: при условии что я уменьшу или увеличу skew ?

Comment: В любом случае. имхо должно все компенисироваться. Если где-то прибавили `skew`, то в другом месте, нужно сделать противоположно, чтоб выровнять фотографию, за исключением когда именно такой эффект фото и предполагался. Но в данном случае вроде как-то не так выглядит....мое мнение, что должно быть как-то так: https://jsfiddle.net/6ywafvtn/

Comment: это мне тоже понравилось , оригинально , хотя по сути одно и тоже , только там js не хватает , хотя в общем нормально ! Но всё же лучший ответ это на poligon т.е  clip-path

Comment: не совсем одно и то же. Как я сказал, у вас изображения "кривятся" Если такой эффект и задумывается - ок. В ином случае - выглядит не камильфо. Я же уравновесил сдвиг одного дива выравниванием картинки в противоположную сторону. В итоге угол есть, а картинка прямая... js и прочее я не добавлял ибо это всего лишь пример вам показать. У меня не было цели сделать всё всё всё. Просто черновичок. Не более..... `clip-path` хорошо, только пока нужны префиксы и не работает в `IE` во всех версиях и даже в `EDGE` и в каком-то из андройдов.

Comment: да согласен про clip-path , но ваше решение мне тоже нравится , но clip-path работает ещё в Опера , сделайте ответом я переизберу в вашу пользу

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам такой вариант. [КодПеро](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/bpzroQ?editors=1100)

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
}
img {
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 90% 100%, 100% 0, 0px 0px);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 90% 100%, 100% 0, 0px 0px);
}
img.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 350px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://hronika.info/uploads/posts/2015-04/1429785852_krasota-kotoruju-mozhno-uvidet-lish-v-illjuminator-samoleta-foto-3.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="img2" src="http://hronika.info/uploads/posts/2015-04/1429785852_krasota-kotoruju-mozhno-uvidet-lish-v-illjuminator-samoleta-foto-3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: не работает во всех браузерах кроме Хрома

Comment: @LenovoID используйте http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path. Для некоторых браузеров нужно добавить SVG-маску и подключать с помощью `url(#mask)`. Я дал вам удочку, ловите :)